# Apache SOLR 4.1 class loader issue with lucene implementation

Tags: tomcat, solr, classloader

I have recently experienced an issue deploying Apache SOLR 4.1 war files to our tomcat 6 servers.  In the server libraries ($CATALINA_HOME/lib) we have an older lucene implementation library (2.9+) for some legacy searching applications.  SOLR has in its .war file WEB-INF/lib the newer, 4.1 lucene implementation jar files.  By checking the Tomcat 6 docs, it appears that the SOLR libraries should load FIRST; however, in experience that is not the case: if I deploy this to a running server, the admin Dashboard shows its loading the 2.9.0 lucene implementation.

To add another twist:  if I STOP and RESTART the Tomcat server, this instead switches to 4.1! As you can probably imagine, this has caused me slave replication grief; as I believe my initial index was built via 2.9 lucene, at some point restarted the container, updated using the then-loaded 4.1, and attempted to replicate to 2.9 lucene-implementation slaves, causing them to all fail.

Any suggestions here would be welcomed.  I tried removing the 4.1 libraries from the SOLR war file, but it fails to load, as some depedencies appear to require them (although the class loader selects the "common library" lucene implementation AFTER deployment!)  It's not feasible to update all the legacy software on these servers to lucene 4, as much re-writing would be involved.  Any idea why the class loaders would perform in this manner?

Edit: to further complicate matters, if I have the SOLR on a freshly-started Tomcat showing 4.1.0 lucene implementation and then RELOAD the core OR do a webapp reload via the Tomcat manager, it GOES BACK to 2.9.0!  This obviously is NOT acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In the given scenario, I would choose to run Solr in another Web Container(may be a **light-weight one like jetty**). But I am not sure if your architecture has that flexibility or you may have concerns over maintainability of these Containers. You can go ahead with this approach provided you are unaffected by these concerns.

The other option is to ask your Tomcat to use your WEB-INF libraries (WEB-INF/lib) for Solr and server libraries ($CATALINA_HOME/lib) for legacy search using lucene.

You can achieve this in Web-logic Server through parameter,

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

in "weblogic.xml" for Solr web-app.

Hope there is an option to do it in Tomcat also!